# Why when i return a variable apeer numbers?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a Script in Powershell that looks for duplicated files and the function that gets the files on a directory and returns the variable with numbers instead of only the files it found.

I did a Write-Host before the return and after it, and the numbers appear at the second print. I don't want the numbers to show, I only want the path of the files.

```
function getFiles($Directory){
$arrayFiles = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
Get-ChildItem $Directory -Name -Recurse -File | % {
        $arrayFiles.Add("$Directory\$_")
    }
    return $arrayFiles
}
$files = getFiles($userInput)
$files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ArrayList.Add()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add(v=vs.110).aspx) emits the index at which it stores a newly added item. You can suppress it by casting the `Add()` statement to type `[void]`:

```
function getFiles($Directory){
    $arrayFiles = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    Get-ChildItem $Directory -Name -Recurse -File | % {
        [void]$arrayFiles.Add("$Directory\$_")
    }
    return $arrayFiles
}
```

That being said, the entire function seems a bit... unnecessary - you can achieve the exact same thing with:

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem $Directory -Recurse -File |Select -Expand FullName)
```